# Closure of a set of functions in $ C([0,\infty),\mathbb{R})$ equipped with $d_\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I am trying to find the closure of $(f_n)\subset C([0,\infty),\mathbb{R})$  equipped with $d_\infty$ where $$f_n(x) = \sin\big(\sqrt{x+4n^2\pi^2}\big)$$for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x\in[0,\infty)$.

Here $C([0,\infty),\mathbb{R})$ means the set of continuous functions from $[0,\infty)$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

I have shown that $f_n\rightarrow 0$ pointwise and so if $(f_n)$ converges in the metric space $\big(C([0,\infty),\mathbb{R}),d_\infty\big)$ then $(f_n)$ converges uniformly and so it must converge to the pointwise limit $0$.

However the convergence is not uniform since for each $n$:

$$\frac{1}{2}\leq\sup_{x\in [0,\infty)}|\sin\big(\sqrt{x+4n^2\pi^2}\big)|.$$ So the closure is just $(f_n)$ itself (since then $(f_n)$ cannot converge uniformly and then cannot converge in the metric space).

Is this correct?

Comment: In fact that $\sup$ equals $1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closure of $(f_n)$ consists of $(f_n)$ and all the limits of subsequences of $(f_n)$. So in order to show that the closure of $(f_n)$ is itself, you need to show that no subsequence of $(f_n)$ converges. The same arguments apply: The only possible limit of a subsequence would be $0$, which is not possible from the inequality you provided.